# Netbeans console does not display Bangla unicode characters

Tags: java

I have a test.txt file with some Bengali character written as

> আমার মাথা, তোমার মাথা

Now when I run this from some packege,

```
import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileInputStream;
import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;

public class Test {
    public static void main( String ajaira[] ) throws FileNotFoundException, IOException
    {
        File f = new File("test.txt") ;
        InputStream is = new FileInputStream(f) ;
        BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader( new InputStreamReader(is) );
        System.out.println("Abs path: " + f.getAbsolutePath() ) ;
        String s ;
        while( (s = br.readLine()) !=null )
        {
            System.out.println(s) ;
        }
    }
}
```

I get some block... well I could not write it. This is the image[image]
Could anyone help with this thing...? Thank you.

Comment: Can you usually display Bengali text in that terminal program? And which terminal program do you use? Which OS? This is not likely to be a Java problem.

Comment: Not sure if you are able to check the encoding of the console using in your IDE.is that the correct encoding you expected?

Comment: @Desworld: vai, matha niya mata mati keno? mojar text dileo parten ;) tobe ai text tao kharap na.

Comment: @Kowser, problem ta niye ashole matha kharap hoye gasilo... :)

Answer (score 21, accepted):

You seem to be using Netbeans. The console in Netbeans uses a Monospace font by default, that is incapable of displaying Bangla characters.

You can switch to a different font from the context menu:

[image: Choose Font for Netbeans Console]

and then opt for displaying all the characters in the console using a font with the Bangla glyphs (I chose Arial Unicode MS, but you can choose any other Bangla font):

[image: Choose Font in Dialog]

This would display the output that you desire:

[image: Display bangla characters]

Also, note the importance of the Netbeans project encoding:

[image: Netbeans project encoding]

Apparently, the console encoding happens to be the same as the project encoding; attempting to change this by setting the `file.encoding` System property yields nothing. In this case, all UTF-8 encoded strings will be displayed without issues. However, if your file happens to be encoded with UTF-16BE/LE or any other encoding scheme, then the console will display gibberish/[mojibake](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mojibake) as it is impossible to change the terminal/console encoding on an as needed basis. In this case, the preferred approach is to store files in the same encoding as the project encoding, so that displaying their contents via `System.out` will not result in displaying gibberish.

Comment: @Hernan Eche" You have to disable "wrap text", to be able to choose font using context menu. Or use options-miscellanous-terminal and set font there. Advantage of this approach is, that this dialogue shows only monospaced fonts and monospaced fonts can use "wrap text" feature

Comment: On Netbeans 8.1 select the 'settings' option from the context menu.

Comment: This didn't work for me. I've been unable to get these characters to display within code in Netbeans.  ✰☆★☞☛❸➂❤♡✉  My project is set as UTF8.  Even "Courier New" didn't work for me, even though it does in Notepad++ with these same characters. I still haven't been able to figure this out.

Comment: I've finally formally asked this as a question here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37644558/netbeans-not-displaying-utf8-unicode-characters-emoticons-correctly

Answer (score 5):

Font download link: [code.google.com](https://code.google.com/p/tuanphamvu/downloads/detail?name=Arial%20Unicode%20MS.rar&can=2&q=)

Here is the look to get solved the font problem in netbeans:[image]

Answer (score 0):

Not NetBeans issue but **Logger encoding issue.** Force Utf8 for Log4j.

It should be default to UTF8 but it wasn't.  Forcing log4j to UTF8 solved my issues.

Symptom: Generated log file was also not in utf8 encoding.

*Still valid for NetBeans 8 to 12*