# How to display unicode strings of variables in Netbeans

Tags: linux, netbeans, netbeans-7

I recently changed into Netbeans for developing my C++ codes, but I faced a strange problem. While trying to watch the program step by step, Netbeans doesn't show the value of Unicode variables correctly, while it doesn't have any problem with ASCII characters.
I checked the settings of my environment, but I couldn't find anything helpful.
Could anyone tell me how I can solve the problem? (I use Netbeans in ubuntu)

Bests.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Are you having an issue seeing the output in the console?  If so, take a look at: [Netbeans console does not display Bangla unicode characters](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7219249/netbeans-console-does-not-display-bangla-unicode-characters) for a possible solution.