# Bangla font is not showing in netbeans

Tags: html, netbeans-8

while I'm trying some code in netbeans-8.0 ide , bangla font is not showing , rather it shows some boxes. But the bangla font and code is perfectly running in any browswer. Now how can I repair my netbeans-8.0 ide???
This is a sample...

```
    <html>
<head>
    <title>Try</title>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
</head>
<body>
    <p>বাংলা লিখা যায় না...</p>
</body>
```

Comment: Browser fonts are potentially quite different from Java application fonts. What sort of system are you running on? How are the bangla fonts deployed?

Comment: I'm running windows 8.1. there is no problem with notepad++ or others. But   the NetBeans ide is not showing any bangla font I am writing. it shows some boxes. But when I'm running the code in browser it is working perfectly...

Comment: No, NetBeans is not showing any warning.

Comment: Check out this question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7219249/netbeans-console-does-not-display-bangla-unicode-characters --> you need to use a font that can display Bangla. However, the example they give is using Arial MS Unicode (and that works, I just tested it), which is a proportional font, which in my opinion makes the editor quite hard to use. So, you'll have to look for a monospaced Bangla font, install that font and set up Netbeans to use that in the editor.