# Non english characters are showing ?? in Action class

Tags: jsp, tomcat, utf-8, configuration, character-encoding

I am submitting following form using jquery ajax and I am printing the values in Action class method. I am using tomcat 7

```xml
<form action="PostNow" id="post_now">
     <s:textarea name="message" style="width:100%;height:80px" 
                   id="text_message" cssClass="form-control" placeholder="Post now">
     </s:textarea>
</form>
```

In action

```
public String insert() {
    HttpServletRequest request = ServletActionContext.getRequest();
    System.out.println("char en "+request.getCharacterEncoding());
    System.out.println("sendor " + message());
}
```

Web.xml

```xml
<Connector port="8080" protocol="HTTP/1.1"
           connectionTimeout="20000"
           redirectPort="8443" URIEncoding="UTF-8"/>
```

In Jsp Page

```xml
<%@page contentType="text/html" pageEncoding="UTF-8"%>
```

In web.xml

```xml
<filter>
    <filter-name>CharacterEncodingFilter</filter-name>
    <filter-class>
        org.apache.catalina.filters.SetCharacterEncodingFilter
    </filter-class>
    <init-param>
        <param-name>encoding</param-name>
        <param-value>UTF-8</param-value>
    </init-param>
    <init-param>
        <param-name>ignore</param-name>
        <param-value>true</param-value>
    </init-param>
</filter>
<filter-mapping>
    <filter-name>CharacterEncodingFilter</filter-name>
    <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
</filter-mapping>
```

I am getting output

> ```
> char en UTF-8
> ?????? ????? ????? ?? ?????? ?? ????
> ```

`??` are hindi characters

How to resolve this ?

Answer (score 1):

You need to run under **UTF-8** your IDE too, to have the output correctly shown in the console.

---

## In Eclipse:

[image]

([source](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14178117/1654265))

---

## In NetBeans:

[image]

Then, be aware that **NetBeans uses a Font not able to reproduce all the UTF-8 characters**, then you need to change it as follows:

[image]

[image]

([source](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7219322/1654265))

Comment: If you send the data to another page (or to the same), does it populate correctly ? If yes, the problem is only in you viewving the file in your IDE console, If no, then the data is converted with a different charset somewhere and the problem is real

Comment: Answer updated, NetBeans console uses a dumb font. If it works, consider upvoting linked answers too

Comment: I tried above step but sop is showing ???. I tried saving message in session and printed in jsp that is correctly showing hindi characters..

Comment: What is *sop* ? BTW if it's showing correctly on JSP, then the problem is only in displaying it in your IDE. IF you've followed both the above steps, it should work: have you ensured the IDE is now on UTF-8 and the console is now using a Font different from the default monospace, and that the new Font is able to draw the characters you want (test it on Word, for example) ? If everything is correct, I'm sorry, I ran out of ideas :/