# How can I enter data using non English (Bangla) language into this database table?

Tags: mysql, sql, database, netbeans, nlp

How can I enter data using non English (Bangla) language into this database table ?
[image]

Comment: You need to change the collation of your table to a UTF-8 flavor which supports Bangla.

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen - utf8 is a "character set"; it supports Bangla.  The "collation" does not matter.

Comment: @RickJames You might want to comment on the answer below, but point taken.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

As pointed out by @Tim you need to change the `collation` of your table/database/column to `UTF-8`. First check the collation of your `database/table/column`.

**CHECK COLLATION:**

**How to check the collation of DATABASE:**

```
SELECT
    default_character_set_name
FROM
    information_schema.SCHEMATA
WHERE
    schema_name = "YOUR_DATABASE_NAME";
```

**How to check the collation of TABLE:**

```
SELECT
    CCSA.character_set_name
FROM
    information_schema.`TABLES` T,
    information_schema.`COLLATION_CHARACTER_SET_APPLICABILITY` CCSA
WHERE
    CCSA.collation_name = T.table_collation
AND T.table_schema = "YOUR_DATABASE_NAME"
AND T.table_name = "YOUR_TABLE_NAME";
```

**How to check the collation of a COLUMN:**

```
SELECT
    character_set_name
FROM
    information_schema.`COLUMNS`
WHERE
    table_schema = "YOUR_DATABASE_NAME"
AND table_name = "YOUR_TABLE_NAME"
AND column_name = "YOUR_COLUMN_NAME";
```

---

**Change COLLATION:**

**How to change database collation:**

```
ALTER DATABASE YOUR_DATABASE_NAME CHARACTER SET utf8 COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci;
```

**How to change table collation:**

```
ALTER TABLE YOUR_TABLE_NAME CONVERT TO CHARACTER SET utf8 COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci;
```

**How to change column collation:**

```
ALTER TABLE YOUR_TABLE_NAME MODIFY YOUR_COLUMN_NAME VARCHAR(255) CHARACTER SET utf8 COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci;
```

**Example:**

```
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS `sample_table`;
CREATE TABLE `sample_table` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `name` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
  `language` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;

INSERT INTO sample_table(name,language) VALUES('Ed Sheeran','English');
INSERT INTO sample_table(name,language) VALUES('আয়েশা খাতুন সুজানা','আমার সোনার বাংলা');
```

Look, the `CHARSET` used in the table definition is `utf8`. So, you can store `unicode characters` in  the table.

Check whether the data inserted correctly or not.

`SELECT * FROM sample_table`;

**Result:**

```
| id |               name |         language |
|----|--------------------|------------------|
|  1 |         Ed Sheeran |          English |
|  2 |    আয়েশা খাতুন সুজানা |  আমার সোনার বাংলা |
```

Comment: Thank you so much for helping me with details , but still not showing

Comment: I guess this issue is not in the `MySQL` side. May be you need to change the font from netbeans settings. Please check this [**POST**](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7219249/netbeans-console-does-not-display-bangla-unicode-characters)

Comment: Have you changed the settings yet in netbeans?

Comment: I tested it in my ide. It's working here. Actually I simulated ur problem and then got out of it. May be u r missing something.

Comment: Ok , then I will definitely try it properly. (ধন্যবাদ)

Comment: Rather than those 3 queries up front, simply do `SHOW CREATE TABLE`.

Comment: What are the netbeans settings?

Comment: Netbeans settings can be found in this [**post**](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7219249/netbeans-console-does-not-display-bangla-unicode-characters). And I just wanted to mention the things specifically. @RickJames

Comment: Please see the tip on using `SELECT HEX...` in http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38363566/trouble-with-utf8-characters-what-i-see-is-not-what-i-stored -- Does `ধন্যবাদ` show hex `E0A6A7 E0A6A8 E0A78D E0A6AF E0A6AC E0A6BE E0A6A6`?  That is correct utf8 encoding.  (Each Bengali character is hex `E0Axxx`.)

Comment: Thanks @RickJames. I will go through it.

Comment: @AyeshaKhatunSujana -- several of my comments are aimed more at you than at Tim.  In particular, let's see the HEX.