# Change all collate fields in mysql

Tags: mysql, collation

I want to change the collation of all my fields in a database. I can change by one at a time with this sentence:

```
UPDATE documentos2 SET titulo = CONVERT(BINARY CONVERT(titulo USING latin1) USING utf8)
```

I need a loop or similar to change all the database fields. Any idea?

Thanx!

Comment: You can check [**this**](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38551591/how-can-i-enter-data-using-non-english-bangla-language-into-this-database-tabl)

Comment: thanx, but it doesn't work for me

Answer (score 0):

Terminology:  `utf8` is a `CHARACTER SET`, not a `COLLATION`.

It is unclear what problem you are trying to solve...

- Perhaps you mistakenly stored utf8 characters in a latin1 field?
- Perhaps you want to re-declare `titulo` as utf8?  (That `UPDATE` will *not* achieve that; it will make a mess.)
- Perhaps `titulo` is already declared utf8, but data was stored incorrectly?
- Something else??

See [Trouble with utf8 characters; what I see is not what I stored](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38363566/trouble-with-utf8-characters-what-i-see-is-not-what-i-stored/38363567#38363567)  In particular, see the `SELECT HEX...` tip.  Please provide the output from such, so we can figure out what got stored.  Also provide `SHOW CREATE TABLE documentos2` so we can know what `titulo` is currently declared as.