# Unable to differentiate between words consisting of different Unicode letters in mysql and phpMyAdmin

Tags: php, mysql, sql, unicode, bengali

I am inserting a word using the following sql query from a php script.

```
$sql = "INSERT IGNORE into cb_words (word, user_id) VALUES('$word', $user_id)";
```

The problem arises in this particular scenario -
The cb_words table contains words in Bangla language.

1. word - আর which encoded to Unicode format is %u0986%u09B0
2. Another word - আঁর which encoded to Unicode format is %u0986%u0981%u09B0

As one may notice from the Unicode encoding for both the words they are almost similar with an additional letter in the second word.

Now, the table - cb_words already contains the second word, but when I am trying to insert the first word it fails.
It does not insert the word and simply says 0 rows inserted.

```
INSERT IGNORE into cb_words (word, user_id) VALUES('আর', 2)
```

When tried from PHPMyAdmin
[image: Insert query result]

Shockingly enough, when I search in the table for the word as -

```
SELECT * FROM `cb_words` where `cb_words`.`word` = 'আর'
```

The returned result is -

[image: The result of the SELECT SQL statement]

N.B: The table only has the word (2) as described above. and I am trying to insert (1)

So, despite the fact, these two words are not 100% identical, why does mysql fail to differentiate between the two?

I am adding the table structure in case it may be necessary:
[image: Table structure for cb_words]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Insert being ignored, is at my guess because your user_id is set to unique? can't tell from your screenshots and you're inserting with IGNORE supressing any errors. Remove the unique index from user_id.

You can change your collation to utf8_bin.

Created your table, locally:

[image: table entries]
[image: result from your select]

similar question with some interesting reading: [How can I enter data using non English (Bangla) language into this database table?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38551591/how-can-i-enter-data-using-non-english-bangla-language-into-this-database-tabl)

Comment: Thanks. Well if I want to change the collation for the table how may I do it without hurting the existing data?

Comment: export your db and try it in a test environment.

Comment: Thanks. The issue has been Fixed. I was doing the complete thing in a test environment locally. Thanks for the great help.

Answer (score 0):

```
mysql> select 'আর'='আর' COLLATE utf8mb4_0900_ai_ci;
+-------------------------------------------------+
| 'আর'='আঁর' COLLATE utf8mb4_0900_ai_ci           |
+-------------------------------------------------+
|                                               1 |
+-------------------------------------------------+
```

That is, declare the column to have `COLLATE utf8mb4_0900_ai_ci`;

The two item you mention have these HEX values:
`E0A686 E0A6B0` and `E0A686 E0A681 E0A6B0`

`E0A681` is a non-spacing-modifier "BENGALI SIGN CANDRABINDU".  When collating with "Accent Insensitive" and (or?) "Case Insensitive", the two are considered equal.

If you want them to be treated as not-equal, use a different collation.