# UTF-8 fonts are not displaying on netbeans and its programs

Tags: java, netbeans

Here is a screenshot: 
 
[image: Valid XHTML].

The font is installed on my computer, so if I copy it from the code to any text editor it shows the font properly. 
 The same problem also occurs in 
the running programs: 
[image: Valid XHTML].

It might be a silly problem, but I couldn't get any helpful answers here.

**edit:** problem solved! see comments section for details.

Comment: [This answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/7219322/522444) might be of relevance to your problem.

Comment: I've just done this, which changed the console fonts to readable, But the coding texts and GUI texts are unchanged :(

Comment: Did you change the fonts of the GUI in your code anywhere? If not, why not?

Comment: No, I think I didn't, e.g. even [this program's](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/examples/components/TextDemoProject/src/components/TextDemo.java) GUI doesn't show the texts properly.

Comment: Then of course, you'll want to do this.

Comment: Yes that worked, thanks! :) I am new about these, so forgive me for asking.

Answer (score 0):

Edit the file `netbeans.conf` from the `etc directory` located at the installation directory of `NetBeans`.

In the `netbeans_default_options` option, add

```
-J-Dfile.encoding=UTF-8
```

Works for both console input and output in NetBeans.