# How to read propositional logic symbols as input using Java Scanner?

Tags: java, input, java.util.scanner

```
 Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in,"UTF-8");
 System.out.println(in.next());
```

If I paste `∧`, I receive `?` as output to the console. Can someone explain what I can do to properly read logic symbols like this? I'm using NetBeans 8.0.1.

Thanks.

Comment: How do you type '∧' ?

Comment: @dejvuth sorry I meant paste.

Comment: This is probably a problem with NetBean. Try http://stackoverflow.com/a/27848261/1547337 or other solutions there

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The problem is not with entering the character, but rather with printing it to console. Your console does not appear to support the code point `\u2227` of `∧`, so it prints a question mark instead.

You should test if console lets you input `∧` correctly by printing the numeric representation of the character that you read, like this:

```
Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in,"UTF-8");
String s = in.next();
if (s.length() != 0) {
    System.out.println((int)s.charAt(0));
}
```

If `8743` gets printed, you could process the character internally: comparisons like this

```
if (s.equals("∧")) {
    ...
}
```

will work correctly.

Otherwise, you should switch to using characters from the first code page, i.e. `^` instead of `∧`

Answer (score 0):

I think your terminal encoding ( IDE or command line ) might not be UTF-8 so when it converts you see the difference.

I just tried your code and got ∧ back.

Do an echo $LC_CTYPE or echo $LANG to check it.

Read this [How to read a text file with mixed encodings in Scala or Java?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13625024/how-to-read-a-text-file-with-mixed-encodings-in-scala-or-java) 
and 
http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/nio/charset/CharsetDecoder.html
for working with different encodings.