# How can I write "Urdu language words" in java Netbeans

Tags: java, netbeans, urdu

I'm trying to make a tailor software for a tailor shop and I have almost done everything, but they want all the words and characters to be in Native Urdu Language, I have tried copying Urdu words from other softwares to Netbeans but it's not working!!
What can I do to solve this issue??

Comment: Can you show an example of what you are copying, what you expect and what is it actually getting displayed ?

Comment: Make sure to store your files with an encoding that can support the Urdu letters.

Comment: You need to post sample code to show what you are doing, and stating that "_it's not working_" does not explain your specific problem at all. Provide enough detail so that others can attempt to reproduce your issue. As it stands the question cannot be answered because it simply does not provide enough information. See [How do I ask a good question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 1):

You are probably running into encoding issue as explained [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4896311/how-to-use-utf-8-character-in-netbeans). You need to add "-J-Dfile.encoding=UTF-8" in netbeans.conf file. Also if you are running your project with maven you might need to add "-Dfile.encoding=UFT-8" in project properties in "Run" section. After doing both of these in a simple maven based java program in netbeans - I can successfully output the Urdu text for "hello" in the netbeans terminal. If you don't do this you would get something like "?????"

[image]