# Display of accented characters in NetBeans 14 for Windows

Tags: java, windows, macos, netbeans, netbeans-14

I currently face to problem with NetBeans when I writeJava code. I use NetBeans 14 and JDK 19.

When I write strings containing accented characters these aren't displayed and replaced with little square forms when I compile the code thank to the compilation function that IDE offers.

I thought that UTF-8 encoding correctly supported accented characters but obviously this is not the case. Or it's me who's cheating on me.

However I'm more than certain to have already used strings containing accented characters. So certain I hurried to test on my Mac using the same version of NerBeans and the JDK !! It’s a crazy thing, I don’t understand all the more because I checked that the settings are the same !!

Here are two screenshots below to help you better understand:

On NetBeans 14 for Mac : https://i.stack.imgur.com/B1gFl.png

On NetBeans 14 for Windows : https://i.stack.imgur.com/zePIg.png

Sorry for the potential orthograph mistakes or syntax errors you could encounter, I'm a French developper.

Comment: I don't understand. Both versions (showing quite different code) show the e acute perfectly well..? *When I write strings containing accented characters these aren't displayed and replaced with little square forms when I compile the code* Compiling doesn't commonly produces any output *at all*. Do you mean when it's run? If so, how are you running it?

Comment: And what does `System.out.println("\u00E9tudier, c'est bon!");` say when you run it?

Comment: seems like the Netbeans console is not displaying UTF-8 correctly (wrong font or encoding) - or its editor is not set to UTF-8. You may try the answer(s) to this question: [How to use UTF-8 character in Netbeans](https://stackoverflow.com/q/4896311/85421) - --- I do not use Netbeans, so I can't test it, but I would check its settings for encoding and font for editor and console

Comment: @g00se Indeed, I did not pay attention to this inconsistency (code difference between screenshots). So I just modified my post by updating the screenshot about NetBeans for Windows. 

Then, to answer your question "Do you mean when it's run? If so, how are you running it?", when I talk about compilation it's when I press the Run project button.


I hope that my additional explanations will be useful to you. I will now try `System.out.println("\u00E9studier, it's good!") ;` as you suggest I do.

Comment: OK, but don't use French in your replies or the question will get closed. My experience is that Windows often does *not* use UTF-8 as its encoding. There are many moving parts including the aforementioned default encoding (shown by `System.out.println(Charset.defaultCharset());`), the encoding setting of the editor and the encoding setting of the console output

Comment: @g00se Excuse me, it's corrected! I had forgotten to translate.

Comment: @g00se I just tested with `System.out.println("\u00E9studier, it's good!");`, but nothing is done... the result is always the same [on NetBeans for Windows].

As for the output displayed by `System.out.println(Charset.defaultCharset());`, the encoding i UTF-8.

Comment: Are you looking at the output in the ide console or the Windows console?